# Google Script GmailApp - Really Confused

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I found a script online that allows me to auto delete emails of a certain label that are older than a certain date.  I've been trying to modify this script to work for me.  I was able to run it once but got a timeout error saying my script was making too many request to the server.  Everytime after that when I tried to run the script I get a server error.  Upon investigating this error using the Execution Transcript int he editor it says I don't have authorization to run the script against my gmail account.  How do I reauthorize this script so that I can run it and test that it is working?

```
function cleanUpForumEmails() {  
  var delayDays = 30; // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash   
  var maxDate = new Date(); 
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);    
  Logger.log("getting gmail labels");
//  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social Updates");  
  var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social Updates");
  Logger.log("got labels now testing for undefined");
  if (labelObject == null) {
    Logger.log("Label is NULL");
  } else {
    var threads = labelObject.getThreads();  
    Logger.log("Label is Set.  Number of Messages in Search: " + threads.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {  
      if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate() < maxDate && threads[i].hasStarredMessages() != true) {  
        if(i < 10) {
          threads[i].moveToTrash();
            Logger.log("Moved Email Thread to Trash!");
          Utilities.sleep(1000);
        } else {
          Logger.log("moved 10 threads now breaking");
          break;
        }
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thwe mail that you want to manipulate is the mail that the scripts is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by including a call to another google script service.  This brought back the authorization page and has been working flawless since then.

the line of code that I used was this:

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

Comment: you could also have use the solution provided in this post answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031107/google-apps-script-calendar-authorization-required-loop/20033077#20033077

Answer (score 0):

If your application is being executed by you and the mail that you want to have access is yours you just need to click in the play button and a windows will appear asking your permission. Once this step is completed it will not ask your permission again.

Comment: Yes me developer account is the same as my mail account.  When I click the button I don't get a new permissions window after I make changes.